# Sklearn Joblib Dump Replace Existing .pkl files

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle, joblib

I'm trying to persist prediction model state by saving my model with

```
joblib.dump(model, path)
```

This works fine, but if I do it twice, the second set of generated .pkl_* files don't really overwrite the old ones, so when I go to call joblib.load(path), I can't be sure it's actually loading in the correct model.

How do I make it so joblib.dump destroys the old .pkl_* files before saving new ones?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a path if you pass in a file opened with "wb" then it will overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to do the "wb" while using joblib. I was facing the similar issue; realising later that I was dumping and loading from different locations.